# Como somar colunas de diferentes dataframes pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando somar colunas entre duas tabelas "diario" e "mensal" como forma de atualizar as colunas "sum" e "count". Entretanto, para algumas linhas a soma retorna vazio. O arquivo "diario" tem 4800 linhas e o mensal 5642 linhas. Para arquivos com menos de 100 linhas não houve esse problema.

O código e as imagens de exemplo são:

```
# Lê ambos os arquivos e armazena em tabelas do Pandas
diario = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/diario.csv')
mensal = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/mensal.csv')

mensal_ini = mensal.copy()
mensal.loc[(mensal['imsi'].isin(diario['imsi'])) & (mensal['operadora'].isin(diario['operadora'])), "sum"] += diario['sum']
mensal.loc[(mensal['imsi'].isin(diario['imsi'])) & (mensal['operadora'].isin(diario['operadora'])), "count"] += diario['count']

mensal = pd.concat([mensal, diario]).drop_duplicates(subset=['imsi','operadora'])

f = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/mensal_result.csv", 'w')
f.writelines(mensal.to_csv(index=False))
f.close()
```

Resultado com falhas em alguns campos de soma:

[image: Tabela mensal atualizada e com erros em algumas linhas]
Figura 1 - Resultado da soma.

As duas tabelas com os campos todos preenchidos, porém que resultam no campo em branco

[image: Tabela "diario"]
Figura 2 - Tabela "diario" com todas as colunas preenchidas.

[image: Tabela "mensal"]
Figura 3 - Tabela "mensal" com todas as colunas preenchidas.

Answer (score 0):

Se você não tiver mais de um mês nas tabelas diário e mensal a solução pode ser:

1. concatenar os dataframes
2. agrupar por imsi e operadora
3. somar colunas valor e cont

Veja abaixo:

### Criar DataFrames teste

```
import pandas as pd
diario_dic = {"imsi": [78, 78, 78, 79, 79, 78, 78, 79, 79], "operadora": ["TIM", "CLARO", "VIVO", "CLARO", "VIVO", "CLARO", "VIVO", "TIM", "TIM"], "valor": [10, 20, 30, 20, 30, 20, 30, 10, 10], "cont": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]}
df_diario = pd.DataFrame(diario_dic)

mensal_dic = {"imsi": [78, 78, 79], "operadora": ["TIM", "CLARO", "VIVO"], "valor": [100, 200, 300], "cont": [10, 20, 30]}
df_mensal = pd.DataFrame(mensal_dic)
```

Valores

```
>>> df_diario
   imsi operadora  valor  cont
0    78       TIM     10     1
1    78     CLARO     20     1
2    78      VIVO     30     1
3    79     CLARO     20     2
4    79      VIVO     30     2
5    78     CLARO     20     2
6    78      VIVO     30     3
7    79       TIM     10     3
8    79       TIM     10     3

>>> df_mensal
   imsi operadora  valor  cont
0    78       TIM    100    10
1    78     CLARO    200    20
2    79      VIVO    300    30
```

### Concatenar os dataframes

```
frames = [df_diario, df_mensal]

df = pd.concat(frames).reset_index()
```

Valor de df

```
>>> df
    index  imsi operadora  valor  cont
0       0    78       TIM     10     1
1       1    78     CLARO     20     1
2       2    78      VIVO     30     1
3       3    79     CLARO     20     2
4       4    79      VIVO     30     2
5       5    78     CLARO     20     2
6       6    78      VIVO     30     3
7       7    79       TIM     10     3
8       8    79       TIM     10     3
9       0    78       TIM    100    10
10      1    78     CLARO    200    20
11      2    79      VIVO    300    30
```

### Agrupar e somar

```
df_result = df.groupby(["imsi","operadora"]).sum().reset_index()
```

Valor de df_result

```
>>> df_result
   imsi operadora  index  valor  cont
0    78     CLARO      7    240    23
1    78       TIM      0    110    11
2    78      VIVO      8     60     4
3    79     CLARO      3     20     2
4    79       TIM     15     20     6
5    79      VIVO      6    330    32
```

Espero que ajude